# Laravel 7 : Image intervention couldn't save into storage

Tags: laravel, image, laravel-7, intervention

I had problems when uploading an image into storage. I used this one before :

```
        
        if ($files) {
          foreach ($files as $file) {
            $imageName = 'gambar_laporan_'.$i.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $upload = Storage::put($filePath.$imageName, file_get_contents($file));
            
          }
        }
```

It works fine before i tried to resize the image using image intervention IO. So i changed my codes to this :

```
$files = $request->file('gambar_laporan');
         
         
         if ($files) {
           foreach ($files as $file) {
             $imageSize = getimagesize($file);

             $newWidth = $imageSize[0] - ($imageSize[0] * 0.3);
             $newHeight = $imageSize[1] - ($imageSize[1] * 0.3);
             $image_resize = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize($newWidth, $newHeight);


             $imageName = 'gambar_laporan_'.$i.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
             $upload = Storage::put($filePath.$imageName, file_get_contents($image_resize));
            
             
           }
         }
```

Then i have this problem

```
file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty
```

What should i do? I cant find any questions that solves this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with this code:

```
        $file = $request->file('gambar_laporan');
        $image = Image::make($file);
        $extension = $filename->extension();
        $file = Str::random(40) . '.' . $extension;
        Storage::put('images' . $file, $image->orientate()->encode($extension), 'public');
        $image->resize(350, 350, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
            $constraint->upsize();
        })->save();

        return $file;
        // It will return the name of image.
```